# Completion suggester builder for Jest

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion, elasticsearch-jest

Is there a built in solution in [jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest) for sending [completion suggester](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) requests to elasticsearch?

Do I need to implement my own `io.searchbox.AbstractAction` for that?

Answer (score 2):

```
Suggest suggest = new Suggest.Builder("{\n" +
                "  \"" + suggestionName + "\" : {\n" +
                "    \"text\" : \"the amsterdma meetpu\",\n" +
                "    \"term\" : {\n" +
                "      \"field\" : \"body\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}").build();

SuggestResult result = client.execute(suggest);
```

Comment: I just realized the question is from 2014